# Using Teradata .net provider from VBA?

Tags: .net, vba, excel, teradata

Does anyone know how I can use the Teradata .NET provider in a VBA project? (excel).  ODBC is not an option.

Comment: What about [OLEDB](http://www.connectionstrings.com/teradata/)?

Comment: so you can used OLEDB from VBA can you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short sad answer: No.

However, you can use it from a .NET program (hence the name), so you could write a C# or VB.NET program which uses it.  If you're a reasonably skilled programmer, you could write a COM component using C#/VB.NET and then you can call that from VBA.

Comment: or use VSTO and build an Application Add-in using C#. Which like VBA ends up embedded in your apllication Excel/Word or whatever.

Comment: @AnthonyLambert - I wasn't going to go that far until it was possible to judge the level of programming competance! But yes, that would be very possible too!

Comment: I think your find VSTO a lot easier than COM/VBA. At least you will if you are okay with C#/VBA.net

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers.  I haven't ventured beyond VBA before, but I think I will try the add-in approach and see how I go!   Cheers :)